# How to handle exceptions in a playframework 2 Async block (scala)

Tags: scala, exception, validation, playframework-2.0

My controller action code looks like this:

```
  def addIngredient() = Action { implicit request =>
    val boundForm = ingredientForm.bindFromRequest
    boundForm.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.Admin.index(formWithErrors)),
      value => {
        Async {
          val created = Service.addIngredient(value.name, value.description)
          created map { ingredient =>
            Redirect(routes.Admin.index()).flashing("success" -> "Ingredient '%s' added".format(ingredient.name))
          }

          // TODO on exception do the following
          // BadRequest(views.html.Admin.index(boundForm.copy(errors = Seq(FormError("", ex.getMessage())))))
        }
      })
  }
```

My Service.addIngredient(...) returns a Promise[Ingredient] but can also throw a custom ValidationException. When this exception is thrown I would like to return the commented code.

Currently the page renders as 500 and in the logs I have:

> play - Waiting for a promise, but got an error: Ingredient with name
>   'test' already exists. services.ValidationException: Ingredient with name
>   'test' already exists.

Two questions:

- Is it a bad idea to return this exception from my service, is there a better/more scala way to handle this case?
- How do I catch the exception?

Comment: There was a bug which has been fixed a few days ago. See [this commit](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/def888333ea435437edb7f70ca3b7f48877af1c7). You can handle runtime exceptions in the `onError` hook of your `Global` object.

Comment: but there is no way to catch the exception locally?

Comment: Yes, you can catch it like any other exception, as shown in the kheraud’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say a pure functional way would have been to use a type that can hold valid and error states.

For that, you can use [Validation](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Validation.odscala.html) form scalaz

But if don't need more than that from scalaz (you will ^^), you could use a very simple stuff using a `Promise[Either[String, Ingredient]]` as the result and its `fold` method in the Async block. That is, `map` to convert the value when the promise is redeemed and `fold` on what is redeemed.

The good point => no exception => every thing is typed check :-)

**EDIT**

It might need a bit of information more, here are the two options: try catch, thanks to @kheraud) and Either. Didn't put the `Validation`, ask me if needed.
    object Application extends Controller {

```
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  //Using Try Catch
  //  What was missing was the wrapping of the BadRequest into a Promise since the Async
  //    is requiring such result. That's done using Promise.pure
  def test1 = Async {
    try {
      val created = Promise.pure(new {val name:String = "myname"})
      created map { stuff =>
        Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("success" -> "Stuff '%s' show".format(stuff.name))
      }
    } catch {
      case _ => {
        Promise.pure(Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("error" -> "an error occurred man"))
      }
    }
  }


  //Using Either (kind of Validation)
  //  on the Left side => a success value with a name
  val success = Left(new {val name:String = "myname"})
  //  on the Right side the exception message (could be an Exception instance however => to keep the stack)
  val fail = Right("Bang bang!")

  // How to use that
  //   I simulate your service using Promise.pure that wraps the Either result
  //    so the return type of service should be Promise[Either[{val name:String}, String]] in this exemple
  //   Then while mapping (that is create a Promise around the convert content), we folds to create the right Result (Redirect in this case).
  // the good point => completely compiled time checked ! and no wrapping with pure for the error case.
  def test2(trySuccess:Boolean) = Async {
      val created = Promise.pure(if (trySuccess) success else fail)
      created map { stuff /* the either */ =>
        stuff.fold(
          /*success case*/s => Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("success" -> "Stuff '%s' show".format(s.name)),
          /*the error case*/f => Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("error" -> f)
        )

      }

  }

}
```

Comment: The type checked solution is clearly better. Thanks for the examples !

Comment: No prob. Here for that ^^. Cheers

Comment: The try-catch solution is not working in play 2.0.1, could be related to the bug/patch Julien was refering to?

Comment: yes most probably. The commit hat he's referring to seems to handle the runtime exceptions in Actions. I don't know what the heck is goin' on now. But I'm guessing that exceptions are lost in the warp ^^

Comment: Loks like scala 2.10 has a helper for this: http://blog.richdougherty.com/2012/06/error-handling-with-scalas-try.html

Comment: Yes I saw! But it's still limited for pure f° usages. And it's ok, because scala isn't purely f°, where ScalaZ is.

Comment: ok, this works if your exception is produced somewhere in your Promise construction. But I have Promises that are made by Akka actors (converted from Akka Futures). These ones sometimes timeout and throw an exception. That is, the Promise throws the exception, somewhere within the Async block. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just catch the exception in your Async block ?

```
Async {
    try {
        val created = Service.addIngredient(value.name, value.description)
        created map { ingredient =>
            Redirect(routes.Admin.index()).flashing("success" -> "Ingredient '%s' added".format(ingredient.name))
        }
     } catch {
         case _ => {
             Promise.pure(Redirect(routes.Admin.index()).flashing("error" -> "Error while addin ingrdient"))
         }
     }
}
```